# Is it possible to fetch and use a file from cloud storage at when deploying a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that makes use of a SQLite database (read-only) which is currently uploaded along with the function.

The problem is that the db file is quite large and gets uploaded every time the function is changed. Is there a way to fetch this file from cloud storage during the installation process (during `firebase deploy`) - without hard-coding the URL in the source files?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is problematic because your code running in Cloud Functions may actually be running on any number of server instances, determined by the load on your project.  As such, downloading a file once at the time of deployment isn't going to naturally affect all the instances that maybe created or destroyed at any given moment.

It's far better to keep doing what you're doing, and include your extra data during deployment.  When a new instance is spun up to handle events for your function, the file will be immediately ready to help service requests.